# Axis2 wsdl2java generated data binding classes

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am using axis2 wsdl2java script to generate client side stubs with the data binding classes being generated separately using the -u option. The generated data binding classes are using the ADB data binder and all the classes are inheriting from the ADBBean. I want the classes to implement the Serializable interface. Is there a way to do this. I have been researching this for a while and haven't been able to find a concrete solution. I need the data binders to be generated separately instead of being inner classes.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but this hint would have save me quite some time few weeks ago. I also struggled with Remoting in Java and tried to get around with Axis2. I ended up with the SpringFramework and their [remoting solutions][1].

  [1]: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html